# Fetch array with $wpdb

Tags: wpdb, array

I am trying to convert this code to use the $wpdb.

```
$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM videos";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query) or die();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_exec)) {
    if ( $row['video'] == "http://youtu.be/".end(explode('http://youtu.be/',$row['video'])) ) {
            $data[$row['id']] = end(explode('http://youtu.be/', $row['video']));
        } else {
            $data[$row['id']] = end(explode('?v=', $row['video']));
        }   
    }
```

So I did:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM videos");
```

But how can I fetch the array?
Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`wpdb`'s `get_results` method takes an optional second argument that lets you specify how the data is returned. The default return is an object. But you can also set it to...

> OBJECT - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of row objects.
>
> OBJECT_K - result will be output as an associative array of row objects, using first column's values as keys (duplicates will be discarded).
>
> ARRAY_A - result will be output as an numerically indexed array of associative arrays, using column names as keys.
>
> ARRAY_N - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of numerically indexed arrays.

(from the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results#SELECT_Generic_Results))

You probably want `ARRAY_A`.

```
<?php
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM videos", ARRAY_A);
```

Unfortunately, `wpdb` doesn't allow you to "stream in" results like you're doing, so you'll need  to use a foreach loop.

```
<?php
foreach($query as $row)
{
    // do stuff with $row here.
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what about this line?
`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_exec)) {`

Comment: See my edit, you just need to use a `foreach` loop instead of `while`.

Comment: Damn, I missed the ARRAY_A the first time, so I got an error in my foreach.
Thank you very much.